# SomeClass* initialEl = new SomeClass[5];

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Should SomeClass* initialEl = new SomeClass[5]; necessarily compile, assuming SomeClass does not have a non-publicly declared default constructor?  Consider:

```
/*
 * SomeClass.h
 *
 */

#ifndef SOMECLASS_H_
#define SOMECLASS_H_

class SomeClass
{

public:
    SomeClass(int){}
    ~SomeClass(){}
};

#endif /* SOMECLASS_H_ */


/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 */

#include "SomeClass.h"

int main()
{
    SomeClass* initialEl = new SomeClass[5];

    delete[] initialEl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `delete[]` when deleting arrays.

Comment: No, you should use `std::vector` so you will always automatically delete. There is zero reason not to use a vector.

Comment: Zero reason?  What about performance in general?  What if I want to use placement new later (which I do)?

Comment: @drenami: What about performance? Performance is a last concern, get your code working in a clean, safe, and maintainable way first, then profile to see what's slow (not guess.) In any case, there's *very* little to no loss in performance. And I don't see the connection to placement new.

Comment: @GMan: I'll look into std::vector, but I'd still like to know what's going on in my question.

Comment: @drenami: You should do more than look into it, you should use it. :) It's part of the language, and any code that uses `new T[]` over `vector<T>` is considered poor code. Also, your question has been answered. If it's not, I suggest you give us a stripped down version of `SomeClass` and tell us the errors you're getting.

Comment: @GMan: Error is "no matching function for call to 'SomeClass::SomeClass'"

Comment: @drenami: This is why you should post real code and real problems instead of other hypothetical code, so you get your real problem answered instead of a hypothetical one. :) You still have your answer, now twice: you need an available default constructor. Your question has double negatives, which make it confusing.

Comment: I don't see a no default constructor in your class.

Comment: In C++0x you can do `new SomeClass[5]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Comment: @Johannes: Is `new SomeClass[5]{0}` or even `new SomeClass[5]{}` a valid way of the same thing?

Comment: @GMan yes both of those work. But sadly, `new SomeClass[]{1, 2, 3}` is not valid (because it wants an expression in the brackets. `new (int[]){1, 2, 3}` is different, but that case is obscured by weird wording in the FCD it seems, which makes GCC reject it by saying "error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds". The Standard does not describe how new-expressions handle the type "T[]" (which is incomplete), but one could interpret it as saying it's analoguous to `T t[] = { ... }`, which would make the *allocated type* (see 5.3.4/1) complete. But wording is unclear, imo

Comment: @GMan in fact the real benefit is that one can say `new T[runtimevalue]{some, initial, values}`. I couldn't find what the Standard says about what happens for cases where the size value is less than the initializer count. Looks like that case is undefined behavior. But on a pedantic view, since it shamelessly defers to section 8.5 for the initializers, one can quote 8.5.1/6: "An initializer-list is ill-formed if the number of initializer-clauses exceeds the number of members or elements to initialize.". That perfectly applies to that new-expression...

Comment: ... but in fact, since we only know at runtime how many elements to initialize, we can't diagnose that! Or we can, by giving a "diagnostic message" at runtime. But i dunno about the standardese of that - sounds weird. So far i have only seen ill-formedness at compiletime, rather than at runtime. GCC isn't of help, sadly. It just says "warning: non-constant array size in new, unable to verify length of initializer-list" :)

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks for all the info. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't compile without a default constructor. There is no compiler-generated default constructor in this case, because you have defined another constructor. "The compiler will try to generate one if needed and if the user hasn't declared other constructors." -- *The C++ Programming Language*, Stroustrup

If you really want to use `new SomeClass[5]`, you'll have to provide a default constructor as well.

Comment: But my compiler notes a candidate as SomeClass::SomeClass(const SomeClass&).

Comment: That is not a default constructor. That is a copy constructor.

Comment: Oh OK!  But explicitly declared?

Comment: Last sentence referred to a deleted comment.

Comment: You must explicitly declare it only because you already explicitly declare another constructor. If there were no constructors, it would make one up. But because you've provided one, it won't. You _could_ alter your current constructor to take a default argument, `SomeClass(int x=0)` because a default constructor can _take_ arguments as long as you can call it _without_ arguments.

Comment: Oh, I also recommend you declare your current constructor as `explicit` to prevent unwanted type conversion.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `SomeClass` has a publicly accessible default constructor, yes.

Note that there is a difference between

1. having a publicly accessible default constructor (what i said) and
2. not having a non-publicly declared default constructor (what you said)

For the following class *2.* is true but *1.* is not:

```
class A {
    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) {}
};
```

This is due to *§12.1/5* (C++03):

> If there is no *user-declared* constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly declared.
>   An *implicitly-declared* default constructor is an `inline public` member of its class.

---

With your update, `SomeClass` doesn't have a default constructor. You didn't declare one and because you have declared another constructor the compiler won't declare it implicitly either.

If you need one you have to implement it yourself:

```
class A {
public:
    SomeClass(int) {}
    SomeClass() {}
};
```

Or let another constructor qualify as a default constructor:

```
class A {
public:
    SomeClass(int=0) {}
};
```

Comment: @drenami: I'm deleting my answer since this one covers it all (great answer). In response to "I have an implcit one. My compiler even tells me so.": You have no implicit constructor since you explicitly made a constructor yourself. The compiler is wrong if it says you have one. (Though I doubt it's actually saying you do.)

Comment: @GMan: your answer had almost no overlap with Georg's (and little to do with my question), but OK.

Comment: @drenami: Ha, ok. I think it's you who doesn't understand and therefore sees them as different. :) His answer is mine plus the why.

Comment: @GMan: I guess my answer is too long anyway ;)

Comment: @GMan: Your answer was about std::vector.
@Fritzsche: ;)

Comment: @drenami: As a solution with your code, I gave the same reasons as Georg and Jon.